# SQL Counting sums of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

Table 1: Fruits
id (int, autoincreasing, primary key)
some other junk

Table 2: Customers
has a 'fruit' column, this column contains an id from the fruit table.

i want to query all the customers, and come up with a list of all the fruit ID's and the number of times they are in use.

So this set up:
Fruits has

```
id    name
1     orange
2     banana
3     apple
```

Customers has 6 rows like:

```
id   fruit
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
```

Trying to write a query that Will give me:

```
fruit id     purchase count
1                  2
2                  4
3                  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT f.id as fruit_id, COUNT(1) AS purchase_count
  FROM FRUITS f LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS c
    ON F.ID = c.fruit
GROUP BY f.id
```

Comment: yes............ now i need to unwrap my head around this fruit bullshit and remember how it applies to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a simple aggregate...

```
SELECT fruit_id, COUNT(fruit_id) AS purchase_count
FROM customers
GROUP BY fruit_id
ORDER BY fruit_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
SELECT id, SUM(fruit) as "fruit id", "purchase count"
FROM Customers
GROUP BY id;
```